# Embed Templates based on GET Parameters in the URL

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

say I have a url like www.site.com/lp?action=workspace

In expression engine, can i do something like

```
if action=workspace{

{embed="landing/form"}

}
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.

Download and use [Mo' Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables).

```
{if "{get:action}" == "workspace"}
  {embed="landing/form"}
{/if}
```

Or if it's a submitted form, POST it instead:

```
{if "{post:action}" == "workspace"}
  {embed="landing/form"}
{/if}
```

But you could consider utilising segments:

> www.site.com/lp/workspace

```
{if "{segment_2}" == "workspace"}
  {embed="landing/form"}
{/if}
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question AND suggesting a better way of doing it.